# Is it possible to stop a function from executing while waiting for an event listener?

Tags: javascript

Using the gmail.js library I wrote this function that receives a string back from an event listener that I want to inject into the body of my email before it is sent. How can I somehow get the function to halt execution while waiting for the Event listener to get the reply from the external script? I have a feeling it can be done with synchronous callbacks but I dont know those well enough to know how to. I'd appreciate any help on the matter.

```
gmail.observe.before('send_message', function(url, body, data, xhr) {

console.log('In the before send message method');

var event = new CustomEvent('Marketing', {

    detail: {
        body: xhr.xhrParams.body_params.body,
        email: gmail.get.user_email()
    }
});

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
    console.log("received a reply");
    console.log(event.data.text);
    newstring = (event.data.candidate);
    console.log(newstring);
    console.log(event.data.token);
    gotNewString = true;
}
});


window.dispatchEvent(event);
console.log('sent the message to extension.js');
function listen(data){
    console.log("123123",JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
}

newstring = "Why must you torture me so?";

var oldCmml = xhr.xhrParams.url.cmml;

var body_params = xhr.xhrParams.body_params;

if (newstring.length > oldCmml) {
    xhr.xhrParams.url.cmml = newstring.length;
} else {
    while (newstring.length < oldCmml) {
        newstring += ' ';
    }
    xhr.xhrParams.url.cmml = newstring.length;
}
console.log(newstring);
body_params.body = newstring;

console.log("sent");

});
```

Comment: i think you likely want the message event to trigger the send, instead of the other way around...

Comment: I wish I could do that, unfortunately, the `observe.before` is an API call that happens when the send button is pressed, this is no other way to execute this code so I HAVE to halt the function from inside somehow

Comment: you can't. even if you could freeze everything with a loop, that would keep the message event from firing. if you can cancel the event from the before, then you can later call `gmail.observe.trigger` with the same (or almost the same) values as the canceled event to "resume".

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the execution of a function inside a callback. You would have to change the code of the calling function, to wait for your function to be finished. This is normally done by supplying a callback function, that you than have to call, once you are done processing, for instance:

```
gmail.observe.before('send_message', function(url, body, data, xhr, done) {
    // you can do processing here

    // and have to call done, to let the caller continue his work
    done();
});
```

For listeners, this is obviously normally not supplied, but since gmail.js is open-source you could change it?